# How do I configure the Kendo Upload widget to hide the files list

Tags: javascript, file-upload, mvvm, kendo-ui

I'm developing with telerik's kendo framework using their mvvm bindings. I'm having trouble with the configuration of the uploader widget, configured as the following:

```
 <input name="files"
               id="fileUploader"
               type="file"
               data-role="upload"
               showFileList="false"
               data-async="{ saveUrl: '/api/', removeUrl: 'remove', autoUpload: true}"
               data-bind="enabled: isEnabled, events: { select: eventAddFile }">
```

How do I configure the [showFileList Configuration option](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/upload#configuration-showFileList) to be false?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use:

```
data-show-file-list="false"
```

Answer (score 0):

The temp solution is this but I would ultimately handle this in the html.

```
uploader = $('#fileUploader').data("kendoUpload");
uploader.options.showFileList = false;
```